# How can I move the ball left/right/up/down using the keybord?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="new 1.css">
    <script src="new 1.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id=redButton type="button" onclick="TurnBallRed()">set ball color red</button>
    <button id=blueButton type="button" onclick="TurnBallBlue()">set ball color blue</button>
    <button id=greenButton type="button" onclick="TurnBallGreen()">set ball color green</button>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="ball">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How can I move the ball left/right/up/down using the keyboard?

I don't want to use jQuery, only JavaScript code.

I tried to use kcode.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you share your JS code ? the one you tried (If you).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so first of all you need to add a new event listener when a keyboard key is pressed you do something within your code. For this step you could do something like this:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
alert('keyboard is being smashed');
});
```

Next, you should get what key was pressed by the user so you can do your action. I learnt this on w3school on [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp). For the second step you could do something like this:

```
if(event.keyCode == 37) {
    alert('Left arrow of keyboard was smashed');
}
else if(event.keyCode == 38) {
    alert('Up arrow of keyboard was smashed');
}
else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    alert('Right arrow of keyboard was smashed');
}
else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
    alert('Down arrow of keyboard was smashed');
}
```

Final code:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
if(event.keyCode == 37) {
    alert('Left arrow of keyboard was smashed');
    //move the ball to left
}
else if(event.keyCode == 38) {
    alert('Up arrow of keyboard was smashed');
    //move the ball to up
}
else if(event.keyCode == 39) {
    alert('Right arrow of keyboard was smashed');
    //move the ball to right
}
else if(event.keyCode == 40) {
    alert('Down arrow of keyboard was smashed');
    //move the ball to down
}

});
```

Comment: its not make the ball move , its only shows alert boxes when i click on the keybord

Comment: I left comments so you implement the movement, I gave you solution of how to detect the keyboard arrows pressing. If you would like me to solve it all post your code of moving the ball.